# fctix how to export user thesaurus?

Tags: fcitx

I have used fcitx for a long time, recently I moved to a new computer, and I want to export my input habit from old computer to new computer, I did not find a way to export, anyone know how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: which input method? e.g. fcitx-mozc stuff might be in ~/.mozc, others will be elsewhere.

Comment: thanks @frostschutz, I found it at your prompt, I am using pinyin input method, and the data is located at `~/.config/fcitx/pinyin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `pinyin` input method, and the data is located at `~/.config/fcitx/pinyin`;

Also find the answer at the link below:

- https://www.oschina.net/question/2359501_246781
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fcitx/iJ6jRL6mlbQ